# Firefox: ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: javascript

Firefox displays the following error in the console:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

In refence to my code which allows me to open embedded youtube videos in fullscreen modals.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".vma_overlay").click(function () {

        var $videoSrcOriginal = $(event.target).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");

        // Check if the embedded youtube url has any attributes appended
        // by looking for a '?' in the url.
        // If one is found, append our autoplay attribute using '&',
        // else append it with '?'.

        if ($videoSrcOriginal.indexOf('?') > -1) {

            var $videoSrc = $videoSrcOriginal

            // when the modal is opened autoplay it
            $('#vma_ModalBox').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // set the video src to autoplay
                var $videoSrcAuto = $videoSrc + "&autoplay=1&mute=1";
                $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrcAuto);

                $('body').addClass("modalyt");
            })

        } else {

            var $videoSrc = $(".vma_iFramePopup").attr("src");

            // when the modal is opened autoplay it
            $('#vma_ModalBox').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // set the video src to autoplay
                var $videoSrcAuto = $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&mute=1";
                $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrcAuto);

                $('body').addClass("modalyt");
            })

        }

        // stop playing the youtube video when modal is closed
        $('#vma_ModalBox').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

            $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrc);

            $('body').removeClass("modalyt");
        })
    });
});
```

Firefox is highlighting the following line of code as being the culprit:

```
var $videoSrcOriginal = $(event.target).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");
```

I don't seem to be having this issue in Chrome, IE or Edge.

I have tried to put it all together in a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/CodeChaos/pen/ZPgbJe

Comment: Why do you expect `event` to be defined?

Comment: `$(".vma_overlay").click(function (event) {...}`

Comment: _"I don't seem to be having this issue in Chrome, IE or Edge"_ - Because that's just another Microsoft way to make things _"work"_ by introducing some arbitrary global variable (`event`) - which got adopted by Chrome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add event to function argument

```
$(".vma_overlay").click(function (event) {

 var $videoSrcOriginal = $(event.target).
```